# I'm trying to create simple wiki parser in C# that would be compatible with trac wiki, but regex is killing me

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, wiki

I need to match non parsed parts first, so I created regex that should catch them:

```
(?<inlinecode>!?\{\{\{(?<inline>.*?)\}\}\})|(?<inlinecode2>!?`(?<inline2>.*?)`)|(?<definition>^\s+((?:`[^`]*`|\{\{\{(?:}{,2}[^}])*?\}\}\}|[^`{:]|:[^:])+::)(?:\s+|$))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FiiBROJkY0otrM1t)

This part gets matched:

```
`test` 
{{{test}}}
`{{{test`
{{{``test}}}
```

But this not (and it should):

```
{{{
test
}}}

{{{#!xxx
test
}}}

def::
  some def
```

What am I missing. RegEx is almost the same as trac uses internally.

Comment: This seems to be a question that is mostly related to regex but you don't provide enough information to those that don't know much about trac wiki or what non-parsed parts are. If you formulate the problem as a regex problem, you'd get more/better answers

Comment: Actually you're right. This is at this point regex problem. All of the above should get matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is correct. You should just **switch on "dot matches linebreak" modifier** or put this `(?:.|[\r\n])` instead of just `.`(dot). *Try this out:*

```
(?<inlinecode>!?\{\{\{(?<inline>(?:.|[\r\n])*?)\}\}\})|(?<inlinecode2>!?`(?<inline2>(?:.|[\r\n])*?)`)|(?<definition>^\s+((?:`[^`]*`|\{\{\{(?:}{,2}[^}])*?\}\}\}|[^`{:]|:[^:])+::)(?:\s+|$))
```

Cheers.